# FirebaseAuth.signInWithCredential is causing my Flutter app to crash when I call it

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm new to Flutter and Firebase. I'm trying to set up Phone Authentication with Firebase. I created a project on Firebase and my Flutter app is registered.

My app keeps crashing when I run FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential).

```
// Successfully ran this and got a verificationID back. 
await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
    phoneNumber: '+18005558989',
    timeout: const Duration(seconds: 0),
    verificationCompleted: verificationCompleted,
    verificationFailed: verificationFailed,
    codeSent: codeSent,
    codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: codeAutoRetrievalTimeout);


// This works
final AuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
  verificationId: argVerificationID,
  smsCode: smsCode,
);

// This is where the app crashes.
AuthResult authResult = await FirebaseAuth.instance
    .signInWithCredential(credential)
    .catchError((onError) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = onError.code;
  var errorMessage = onError.message;

  // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
  var credential = errorCode.credential;

  print("ERROR CODE:$errorCode");
  print("ERROR MESSAGE:$errorMessage");
  print("ERROR CREDENTIAL:$credential");
});
```

Here is the Error Output:

> W/BiChannelGoogleApi(23681): [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod()
>   returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzak@30ab46a
>   E/JavaBinder(23681): *** Uncaught remote exception!  (Exceptions are
>   not yet supported across processes.) E/JavaBinder(23681):
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
>   Landroid/support/v4/util/ArrayMap; E/JavaBinder(23681):   at
>   com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzam.zzc(Unknown Source:22)
>   E/JavaBinder(23681):  at
>   com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzam.zzde(Unknown Source:17)
>   E/JavaBinder(23681):  at
>   com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzam.zzdd(Unknown Source:8)
>   E/JavaBinder(23681):  at
>   com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzan.zzdf(Unknown Source:1)
>   E/JavaBinder(23681):  at
>   com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzm.isAnonymous(Unknown Source:47)
>   E/JavaBinder(23681):  at
>   com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzat.zzi(Unknown Source:57)
>   E/JavaBinder(23681):  at
>   com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzat.zzg(Unknown Source:10)
>   E/JavaBinder(23681):  at
>   com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.zza(Unknown Source:62)
>   E/JavaBinder(23681):  at
>   com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth$zzb.zza(Unknown Source:5)
>   E/JavaBinder(23681):  at
>   com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzcv.zzdx(Unknown Source:14)
>   E/JavaBinder(23681):  at
>   com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzen.zzen(Unknown Source:35)
>   E/JavaBinder(23681):  at
>   com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzen.zza(Unknown Source:41)
>   E/JavaBinder(23681):  at
>   com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzep.zza(Unknown Source:9)
>   E/JavaBinder(23681):  at
>   com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzdx.dispatchTransaction(Unknown
>   Source:9) E/JavaBinder(23681):    at
>   com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_auth.zza.onTransact(Unknown
>   Source:13) E/JavaBinder(23681):   at
>   android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1021)
>   E/JavaBinder(23681):  at
>   android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:994) E/JavaBinder(23681):
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "android.support.v4.util.ArrayMap" on path: DexPathList[[zip file...

I'm expecting a FirebaseUser return and successfully authenticated. It looks like Firebase updated their authentication because a lot of the  methods that are found used in tutorials are no longer there.

Comment: try to migrate your android project to android X

Comment: @PraneethDhanushkaFernando - I just tried migrating to AndroidX. Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX. It said no usage in the project; app is still crashing from calling FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential).

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else runs into this problem, this happened because while developing the Flutter app, Android Studio prompted a new version of Flutter is available and I hit upgrade. But a manual flutter upgrade needed to be executed in the Terminal and upgrading Kotlin to the latest version.

Steps I took to solve this issue:

Updated the following files:

1. **project_folder/android/build.gradle**. Changed "ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.71'" to "ext.kotlin_version='1.3.50'"
2. **project_folder/android/gradle/gradle-wrapper.properties**. Set distributionUrl to the latest gradle, "distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip". Android Studio notified to use the latest gradle and stated where to make the change.
3. Add these two lines to project_folder/android/gradle.properties:

   ```
   android.useAndroidX=true
   android.enableJetifier=true
   ```

Then go to Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX. Waited for that to complete then ran the bottom commands in the terminal.

Commands to run in Terminal (Mac OS):

1. $ **flutter upgrade**
2. $ **flutter pub upgrade**
3. $ **flutter clean**

That did it for me. Now when I run

```
    await FirebaseAuth.instance
    .signInWithCredential(credential).then((authResult){
      print(authResult.user);})
```

I get an AuthResult object returned back with the FireBaseUser object inside of it. Here is the output:

```
FirebaseUser({uid: yZXXXXXXXXXXXX, isAnonymous: false, phoneNumber: +18005558989, ...})
```

Comment: It was working for couple of hours then it failed again. Just updated to AndroidX. I had to android/gradle.properties and add these two lines:  'code'

Answer (score 0):

- Open on Android Studio on your Flutter Project
- **Then, Update all gradle and kotlin and migrate kotlin**
- **Then, Migrate to Android X**
- Then, Open Flutter Project
- Flutter Upgrade
- Flutter pub Upgrade
- Flutter Clean